# How to select records from a table and adding to another table One to many

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called logentry which has a 1 to many relationship with a table called logentryfiles. the following is the table structure for log entry. Basically I am normalizing my database and I need to populate the new table from the existing logentry table. I am having difficulty while composing the SQL statement.

```
logentry table

id
outfilename
outfilestoredname
jsonfilename
jsonfilestoredname
logfilename
logfilestoredname

logfiles table

id
filename
filestoredname
fileextension
logentry_id
```

Sample data in logentry table

```
ID 1
jsonfilename E:\EP3\loadlist\5252012CTRLChagasSyphLL.JSON
jsonfilestoredname E:\RunLog\App_Data\uploads\2012\May\31\29fe57db-f159-4f29-8ce1-609c46671aa9.json
outfilename  E:\HIVLoadlist80.out
outfilestoredname E:\RunLog\App_Data\uploads\2012\Jul\26\f691a988-5197-4171-aa49-027b6b7c6242.out
logfilename C:\Users\larsemm\Documents\Outside Work\Reliability Database Testing Files\ICQ Log\Log File 1\Server_051713-154319_Results.log
logfilestoredname E:\RunLogTest\App_Data\uploads\2013\Sep\11\72c62705-6c28-4efc-bb53-f45c381be9dd.log
```

So the above data will look like the follows in the logfiles table

```
id  1
logentry_id 2
storedfilename  E:\RunLog\App_Data\uploads\2012\May\31\29fe57db-f159-4f29-8ce1-609c46671aa9.json
filename E:\EP3\loadlist\5252012CTRLChagasSyphLL.JSON
fileextension JSON
```

second row

```
id  2
logentry_id 2
storedfilename  E:\RunLog\App_Data\uploads\2012\Jul\26\f691a988-5197-4171-aa49-027b6b7c6242.out
filename  E:\HIVLoadlist80.out
fileextension OUT
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO logfiles (filename
,filestoredname
,fileextension
,logentry_id)

SELECT 
,jsonfilename AS filename
,jsonfilestoredname AS storedname
,'JSON' AS extension
,id
FROM logentry L
UNION
SELECT 
,outfilename AS filename
,outfilestoredname AS storedname
,'OUT' AS extension
,id
FROM logentry L
UNION
SELECT 
,logfilename AS filename
,logfilestoredname AS storedname
,'LOG' AS extension
,id
FROM logentry L
```